# How many daily analytic snapshots can I schedule in the Professional Edition of Salesforce.com

Tags: salesforce

I am using the Professional Edition of Salesforce.com.

I would like to setup several different analytic snapshots to run daily. However when I try to schedule the second snapshot I can find no available start times. I have checked the [Professional Edition Limits](http://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/limits.htm#ReportAndDashboardLimitDetails) but they are not clear on exactly how many snapshots can be scheduled.

How many analytic snapshots I can schedule daily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked Salesforce support and got this reply.

> To clarify for you, you can only schedule one Analytic Snapshot to start on any given day on Professional Edition.